# How to create connected sliders in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2

I'm trying to create a control with 3 vertical sliders. I want the draggable dots on the sliders to have lines connecting them. Any advice on how to go about making this?

Comment: any screenshot or code where you try to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `UIBezierPath`, use that path in a `CAShapeLayer`, and add that layer as a sublayer to your view's `layer`.

The only issue is figuring out the start and end points for your lines, and that can be done by looking at the sliders' `thumbRectForBounds`. And assuming you used a standard `UISliderView` and simply rotated it, you should make sure to convert the point to the parent's coordinate system:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider1: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider2: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider3: UISlider!

    lazy var lineLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.lineWidth = 3
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        return layer
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        [slider1, slider2, slider3].forEach { slider in
            slider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
        }

        view.layer.insertSublayer(lineLayer, atIndex: 0)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        lineLayer.frame = view.bounds

        updatePathBetweenSliders()
    }

    @IBAction func didChangeValue(sender: UISlider) {
        updatePathBetweenSliders()
    }

    private func updatePathBetweenSliders() {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(slider1.thumbCenter())
        path.addLineToPoint(slider2.thumbCenter())
        path.addLineToPoint(slider3.thumbCenter())
        lineLayer.path = path.CGPath
    }
}
```

Where:

```
extension UISlider {
    func thumbCenter() -> CGPoint {
        let thumbRect = thumbRectForBounds(bounds, trackRect: trackRectForBounds(bounds), value: value)
        let thumbCenter = CGPoint(x: thumbRect.midX, y: thumbRect.midY)

        return convertPoint(thumbCenter, toView: superview)
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image: lines between sliders]

If you want to animate the sliders at any point (like I do at the end of that animated GIF), you'll probably have to resort to a `CADisplayLink` to update the values:

```
let animationDuration = 0.5
var originalValues: [Float]!
var targetValues: [Float]!
var startTime: CFAbsoluteTime!

@IBAction func didTapResetButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let sliders = [slider1, slider2, slider3]

    originalValues = sliders.map { $0.value }
    targetValues = sliders.map { _ in Float(0.5) }

    startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(handleDisplayLink(_:)))
    displayLink.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}

func handleDisplayLink(displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
    let percent = Float((CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime) / animationDuration)
    let sliders = [slider1, slider2, slider3]

    if percent < 1 {
        for (index, slider) in sliders.enumerate() {
            slider.value = (targetValues[index] - originalValues[index]) * percent + originalValues[index]
        }
    } else {
        for (index, slider) in sliders.enumerate() {
            slider.value = targetValues[index]
        }
        displayLink.invalidate()
    }

    updatePathBetweenSliders()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was very useful. I am curious -- is there a way to do this without using the transform property? Transformations don't abide by autol ayout, making it difficult to position these vertical sliders cleanly. I tried putting them in a stack view, but I ran into all sorts of issue while trying to get the size I wanted.

Comment: I tried putting them in a stack view and found that to be more complicated when you had transformations involved. I rendered the above using transformed sliders with auto layout and it worked surprising well (though the storyboard looked weird). You certain could make your own vertical slider control, too, though, as it's not that complicated. And I'm sure there are third party vertical slider controls out there, though I haven't really looked and certainly can't vouch for any.